# Multiple DocumentRoot in Apache2

Tags: debian, http, apache2

We currently have a Turnkey appliance running with Debian and Apache2 for testing purposes.

The Apache config file looks like this:

```
ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/owncloud/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/owncloud/

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /usr/share/owncloud/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

We have something installed in /var/www/html and want to redirect everything https://example.com/extras/* to /var/www/html. We tried to use Alias and it wasn't working, maybe we didn't apply it correctly.

Comment: Edit the question to provide specific details about how it was not working- what happened in response to what action.

Answer (score 0):

You likely just need a  block for the other directory you want to serve from, that is configured like the one you have for owncloud- along with the Alias directive that you likely used. This combination of Alias and Directory will permit apache to serve from that other directory for that http route.

DocumentRoot just provides a default mapping, think of it like

Alias / /filesystem/path